# Обработка JSON на JS

Tags: javascript, json

Столкнулся с срочной необходимостью написать небольшой скрипт на JS (на котором никогда не работал), который бы обрабатывал JSON. Проблема заключается вот в чём. В этом JSON присутствует поля вида: `field_name/_link`, `field_name/_text`. 
Обычные поля обрабатываются нормально (без `/`), но при попытки запросить поле `.field_name/_text`, выдаётся ошибка о не определённости данного поля.

Объясните пожалуйста, какую роль выполняет символ `/` в JSON или JS. Главная проблема в том, что я не знаю где, и что искать.

Comment: а так не пробовали? obj['field_name/_link']

Comment: @Jean-Claude Мда, всё просто. Огромное спасибо. Пытался вкурить документацию по JSON, а оказалось всё намного проще. Спасибо.

Comment: я не спец, но это не совсем JSON, скорее доступ к элементу объекта, а они немного отличаются.

Comment: @Jean-Claude В этом проблема и была, что я искал про JSON, а оказалось, что это чисто синтаксис JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает у меня:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#but').on('click', function(){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"field_name/_link":"someValue"}');
    alert("field_name/_link: " + obj['field_name/_link']);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="but" value="alert" type="button">
```